# AJAX response keep increasing without loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing promote and demote system. Result will update and show immediately once user click on the button. The function is working properly. But I figured out, if I keep pressing the promote / demote button. The loading time will keep increasing. So I try to check the Console by using Firebug and I found out this problem regarding to AJAX response.

The response keep on increasing once I press the button.

I will attach the screenshot.

[image]

From the image, you can see the AJAX response when I click the button for first time and second time.

[image]

This is the result when AJAX response when I click for third time. The number will keep increasing until my browser crash.

I will attach my Javascript code here.

Feel free to correct my bad coding. I'm will appreciate it.

This is the displayTable function which include some extra click event function.

```
function displayTable() {

$('#tableContent').empty();

$.post(base_url + "index.php/resident_detail_controller/selectAllUser", {}, function(data) {

    $('#tableContent').html(
            "<input type='hidden' id='totalRows' value='" + data.result.length + "' />" +
            "<table class='table table-bordered table-list-search sortable'>" +
            "<thead>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>#</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Email</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Full Name</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Contact Number</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Status</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Action</th>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</thead>" +
            "<tbody>");

    if (data.status === 'Success') {

        for (var j = 0; j < data.result.length; j++) {

            if (data.result[j].Category === "N") {
                $('tbody').append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + j + "</td>" +
                        "<td><input type='hidden' id='email" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].Email + "' />" + data.result[j].Email + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data.result[j].FullName + "<input type='hidden' id='fullName" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].FullName + "'/></td>" +
                        "<td>" + data.result[j].ContactNo + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='text-center'>" + data.result[j].Category + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='text-center'>" +
                        "<button type='button' id='btnPromote" + (j + 1) + "' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btnPromote' value='" + (j + 1) + "'>Promote</button>" +
                        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up'></i>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
            } else {
                $('tbody').append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + j + "</td>" +
                        "<td><input type='hidden' id='email" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].Email + "' />" + data.result[j].Email + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data.result[j].FullName + "<input type='hidden' id='fullName" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].FullName + "'/></td>" +
                        "<td>" + data.result[j].ContactNo + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='text-center'>" + data.result[j].Category + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='text-center'>" +
                        "<button type='button' id='btnDemote" + (j + 1) + "' class='btn btn-sm btn-info btnDemote' value='" + (j + 1) + "'>Demote</button>" +
                        "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
            }
        }

        $(document).on("click", ".btnPromote", function(event) {

            //var index = $(this).attr('value');
            var index = String(event.target.value);

            var email = $('#email' + index).val();
            var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
            $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/promoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

                if (data.status === 'Success') {
                    notif({
                        msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                        type: 'success'
                    });

                    $('#tableContent').empty();
                    displayTable();
                } else {
                    notif({
                        msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }

            }, 'JSON');
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".btnDemote", function(event) {

            var index = String(event.target.value);

            var email = $('#email' + index).val();
            var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
            $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/demoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

                if (data.status === 'Success') {
                    notif({
                        msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                        type: 'success'
                    });

                    $('#tableContent').empty();
                    displayTable();
                } else {
                    notif({
                        msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }

            }, 'JSON');
        });

        $('#tableContent').append("</tbody></table>");
    }
}, "JSON");
```

This is the code when user click on the Promote / Demote button.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('.btnPromote').click(function(event) {

    //var index = $(this).attr('value');
    var index = String(event.target.value);
    var email = $('#email' + index).val();
    var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
    $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/promoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

        if (data.status === 'Success') {
            notif({
                msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                type: 'success'
            });

            $('#tableContent').empty();
            displayTable();
        } else {
            notif({
                msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                type: 'error'
            });
        }

    }, 'JSON');
});

$('.btnDemote').click(function(event) {

    //var index = $(this).attr('value');
    var index = String(event.target.value);
    var email = $('#email' + index).val();
    var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
    $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/demoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

        if (data.status === 'Success') {
            notif({
                msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                type: 'success'
            });
            $('#tableContent').empty();
            displayTable();
        } else {
            notif({
                msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                type: 'error'
            });
        }

    }, 'JSON');
}
);
```

});

Comment: Every time you call `displayTable()`, you're binding another set of click handlers to all the buttons. So when you click on the button, it runs all the handlers that you've bound. You should normally only bind event handlers at the top level, not inside other event handlers.

Comment: @Barmar, what should I do to overcome this issue?

Is that mean if can try not to use
$(document).on("click", ".btnDemote", function(event)?

Comment: You should put that in the `$(document).ready()` handler, not in `displayTable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.on("click")` bindings from `displayTable()`, and replace the `.click()` bindings in your document ready handler with them.

You also don't need to append `'</tbody></table'`. When you append elements to the DOM, you're adding whole elements, not bits of HTML strings. So when you append the `<table>`, the `</table>` is part of that element, and it's already in there.

I also recommend using `$("#tableContent").on("click", ".btnPromote", ...)`. You should delegate the handler from the closest enclosing static element. Delegation works by binding a handler to the element you apply it to, and it has to check whether the target matches the selector; this way you don't run the handler unnecessarily.

```
function displayTable() {

    $('#tableContent').empty();

    $.post(base_url + "index.php/resident_detail_controller/selectAllUser", {}, function(data) {

        $('#tableContent').html(
            "<input type='hidden' id='totalRows' value='" + data.result.length + "' />" +
                "<table class='table table-bordered table-list-search sortable'>" +
                "<thead>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>#</th>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Email</th>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Full Name</th>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Contact Number</th>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Status</th>" +
                "<th class='text-center' style='font-size: 16px'>Action</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody>");

        if (data.status === 'Success') {

            for (var j = 0; j < data.result.length; j++) {

                if (data.result[j].Category === "N") {
                    $('tbody').append(
                        "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + j + "</td>" +
                            "<td><input type='hidden' id='email" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].Email + "' />" + data.result[j].Email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.result[j].FullName + "<input type='hidden' id='fullName" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].FullName + "'/></td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.result[j].ContactNo + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='text-center'>" + data.result[j].Category + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='text-center'>" +
                            "<button type='button' id='btnPromote" + (j + 1) + "' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btnPromote' value='" + (j + 1) + "'>Promote</button>" +
                            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up'></i>" +
                            "</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                } else {
                    $('tbody').append(
                        "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + j + "</td>" +
                            "<td><input type='hidden' id='email" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].Email + "' />" + data.result[j].Email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.result[j].FullName + "<input type='hidden' id='fullName" + (j + 1) + "' value='" + data.result[j].FullName + "'/></td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.result[j].ContactNo + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='text-center'>" + data.result[j].Category + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='text-center'>" +
                            "<button type='button' id='btnDemote" + (j + 1) + "' class='btn btn-sm btn-info btnDemote' value='" + (j + 1) + "'>Demote</button>" +
                            "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></i>" +
                            "</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                }
            }
        }
    }, "JSON");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableContent").on("click", ".btnPromote", function(event) {

        //var index = $(this).attr('value');
        var index = String(event.target.value);

        var email = $('#email' + index).val();
        var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
        $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/promoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

            if (data.status === 'Success') {
                notif({
                    msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                    type: 'success'
                });

                $('#tableContent').empty();
                displayTable();
            } else {
                notif({
                    msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                    type: 'error'
                });
            }

        }, 'JSON');
    });

    $("#tableContent").on("click", ".btnDemote", function(event) {

        var index = String(event.target.value);

        var email = $('#email' + index).val();
        var username = $('#fullName' + index).val();
        $.post(base_url + 'index.php/resident_detail_controller/demoteUser', {email: email}, function(data) {

            if (data.status === 'Success') {
                notif({
                    msg: '<b>You had successfully promoted ' + username + '</b>',
                    type: 'success'
                });

                $('#tableContent').empty();
                displayTable();
            } else {
                notif({
                    msg: '<b>You fail to promote ' + username + '</b>',
                    type: 'error'
                });
            }

        }, 'JSON');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciated it very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're adding a new event handler with these two lines:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnDemote", function(event) {

$(document).on("click", ".btnDemote", function(event) {
```

for every time you do this operation.  Over time, these will pile up and every click will call than event handler a whole bunch of times causing you to do N ajax calls for every click (where N continually grows).

Because these are attached to the document object, these event handlers should be set up ONCE at initialization time and never installed again.

Comment: What can I do to overcome this issue?
Sorry, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Move the installation of those event handlers outside of the `displayTable()` function to someplace that they are only done once when your page is first loaded.

Comment: I will vote this answer once I had enough reputation. Thanks!!